# How to mock a third party React component using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

TLDR; **what's the proper way to mock a React component imported from a third-party library?**

I'm testing a component called `<App/>`. It consumes a 3rd part component called `<Localize/>` provided by a library called `localize-toolkit`.

I'm having some trouble mocking `<Localize/>` using Jest.

Here is how I've tried mocking it.

```
jest.mock('localize-toolkit', () => ({
  // Normally you pass in a key that represents the translated caption.
  // For the sake of testing, I just want to return the key.
  Localize: () => (key:string) => (<span>{key}</span>)
}));
```

And I've written a unit test for `<App/>` that looks like this.

```
it('Test', () => {
    const component = render(<App/>);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  }
)
```

It will pass, however this is the warning message returned.

`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render.`

And when I look at the snapshot, I get a series of periods "..." where the localized caption should appear.

Am I not mocking the `Localize` component properly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it.

Note how the third-party component `Localize` needs to be returned as a function.

```
jest.mock('localize-toolkit', () => ({
  Localize: ({t}) => (<>{t}</>)
}));
```

and in case there are multiple components, and you only want to mock one of them, you can do this:

```
jest.mock("localize-toolkit", () => {
    const lib = jest.requireActual("localize-toolkit");

    return {
        ...lib,
        Localize: ({t}) => (<>{t}</>), 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

We can mock the 3rd party library for example in my case i need to mock **react-lazyload**

Component.tsx

```
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';

render() {
  <LazyLoad><img/></LazyLoad>
}
```

In jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
   'react-lazyload': '/jest/__mocks__/react-lazyload.js',
  }
}
```

In jest/**mocks**/react-lazyload.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

jest.genMockFromModule('react-lazyload');

const LazyLoad = ({children}) => <>{children}</>;

module.exports = { default: LazyLoad };
```