# Mock custom hook from 3rd party library in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-hooks

I am using a custom hook from 3rd party library in my React project:

```
import { useProductData } from '@third/prod-data-component';

const ProductRow: React.FC<MyProduct> = ({ product }) => {
  // using the custom hook here
  const productData = useProductData();
})
```

The signature of that hook function is:

```
export declare const useProductData: () => string | undefined;
```

In my jest test, I would like to mock the returned value of the hook, I tried:

```
it('should show correct product data', ()=>{
   jest.mock('@third/prod-data-component', () => {
      return { useProductData: jest.fn(()=>'foo')}
   });
   ...
   ...
})
```

When I run test, the above mock doesn't take any effect.

How to mock the return value of custom hook that is from a 3rd party library?

==== UPDATE ====

I also tried this:

```
jest.mock('@third/prod-data-component', () => {
            const lib = jest.requireActual('@third/prod-data-component');
            return {...lib, useProductData: () => 'foo'}
        });
```

But does't work either.

Comment: have you tried `jest.requireActual("@third/prod-data-component");`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka could you please provide more detail how to use that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034748/how-to-mock-a-third-party-react-component-using-jest

Comment: Tried, doesn't work for me...

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I updated my post with what you suggested.

Comment: have you tried updating the `jest.config.js` suggested in the same qustion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
import {useProductData} from '@third/prod-data-component'

jest.mock('@third/prod-data-component');

(useProductData as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {mockKey: 'mockData'})

describe('test scenario', () => {
  it('should show correct product data', () => {
    // your assertions
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your example, you may be missing the actual module import.

However, have you tried the [full module mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules)?

```js
import moduleMock from '@third/prod-data-component'

jest.mock('@third/prod-data-component')

describe('test scenario', () => {
  it('should show correct product data', () => {
    moduleMock.useProductData.mockReturnValue(...)
  })
})
```

### EDIT

I missed the Typescript part. You need to wrap the actual module type definitions with Jest's own type definitions.

I solved this problem in the past in the following way, using [`jest.mocked`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedsource-options) function:

```js
import prod_data_component_module from '@third/prod-data-component'

jest.mock('@third/prod-data-component')

describe('Your test case scenario', () => {
  const mock = jest.mocked(prod_data_component_module, { shallow: true })

  it('Your test here', async () => {
    mock.useProductData.mockReturnValue('...')

    // test logic here
  })
})
```

`mock` is a **jest** wrapper of the original module. It is of type `jest.MockedFn<T>`, so it contains actual exported types/functions and also jest mocks.

Comment: I tried your answer but get `Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type '() => string | undefined'.ts(2339)`

Comment: You need to wrap the actual module type definitions with jest types. I'll add another answer later with a clearer explanation

Comment: Thanks but the compiler is complaining that `{shadow: true}`, `(property) shallow: boolean
No overload matches this call.`

Comment: @SAHIL 's answer works. But thank you anyway.